# How can i rewrite assembly code using Dos to NASM assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, emu8086

how can i convert this assembly code using Dosbox to classic i8086 NASM code which can be compiled on Win? Program must run on Intel 8086.

```
.model SMALL
.stack 50
.data
    RET1    DB 10,13,'Bolo zadane iba jedno slovo$'  
    POCET   Dw 0                     
    poc db 0                    
    zhod    dw 0                    
    sum db 0                    
    suma    dw 0                     
    jed db 0                     
    des db 0                    
    sto db 0                     
.code

getchar PROC                        
    MOV AH,01
    INT 21H
    RET
getchar ENDP

napln   proc                
    mov ax,50           
    mov si,ax
    mov ax,150          
    mov di,ax
    mov cx,pocet
pokr:   mov bl,[si]         
    mov [di],bl
    inc di
    inc si
    dec cx
    cmp cx,0
    jnz pokr
    ret 
napln   endp

START:  mov ax,50           
    mov si,ax
    MOV AX,@data
    MOV DS,AX
        
slovo:  CALL getchar            
    CMP AL,32           
    JZ MEDZ             
    CMP AL,13           
    JZ malo             
    cmp poc,0           
    mov cx,pocet            
    
    jnz kontr           
skok:   mov [si],al         
    inc si              
    INC POCET           
    inc poc
    JMP slovo           

kontr:  mov si,50           
kon:    cmp al,[si]         
    jz slovo            
    inc si              
    dec cx              
    cmp cx,0            
    jnz kon             
    jmp skok            

MEDZ:   cmp poc,0           
    jz slovo            
    call napln          
    CALL GETCHAR            
    CMP AL,13           
    JZ MALO             
    CMP AL,32           
    JNZ CITAT           
    JMP MEDZ            

malo:   MOV DX,offset RET1      
    MOV AH,09
    INT 21H 
    mov ax, 4c00h           
    INT 21h
    
CITAT:  CMP AL,13           
    JZ posledne         
    cmp al,32           
    jz space            
    mov si,150          
    mov cx,pocet            
    
zisti:  cmp al,[si]         
    jnz dalej           
    mov bl,0            
    mov [si],bl         
    inc zhod            
dalej:  inc si              
    dec cx              
    cmp cx,0            
    jnz zisti
    
dalsi: CALL GETCHAR         
    JMP CITAT           

posledne: mov cx,pocet          
      cmp zhod,cx           
      jnz prevod            
      inc sum           
      inc suma
      jmp prevod            
    
space:  mov cx,pocet            
    cmp zhod,cx
    jnz zle             
    inc sum             
    inc suma
zle:    mov zhod,0          
    call napln          
    jmp dalsi           

prevod: jmp vypis

vypis:  
    MOV AH,02
    MOV DL,0AH
    INT 21H
    MOV AL,sum
    ADD AL,48
    MOV DL,AL
    INT 21H 
    mov ax, 4c00h
    INT 21h

END START
```

Or can someone do it? The program should list the number of words containing all the letters of the first word from the input string. The statement should be in the decimal system. This is my first experience with assembly language so i dont know how can i do it

Comment: DOSBox is a VM, not an assembler dialect. This looks like MASM or TASM code.

Comment: You seem to be implying something about Windows, as in porting this code to run as a native (32 or 64-bit) Windows executable, rather than running in 16-bit mode?  That's a totally separate thing from porting the syntax to NASM.  Both MASM and NASM can create 16-bit DOS, or 32 or 64-bit Windows, object files.  The syntax change is fairly straightforward if you read NASM's manual about differences from MASM (https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2), but does nothing to help it work as a Windows program.

Answer (score 2):

A first step might be to convert the code to NASM source code for DOS. To do this you'd mostly delete the unnecessary stuff (e.g. `getchar PROC` becomes `getchar:`, `getchar ENDP` gets deleted, etc). You'd also have to figure out how to get NASM to generate a DOS compatible ".exe" file (see https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc9.html#section-9.1 ). After doing that (and testing that it works properly); a second step might be to convert the NASM source code for DOS into NASM source code for Windows.

However; Windows uses very different APIs with more baggage. Specifically, you're supposed to use DLLs (and dynamic linking) so that Microsoft can radically change the kernel's API without breaking everything, and the kernel's APIs are deliberately undocumented to try to prevent people from writing code that will break when the kernel is changed. For some of it; the nature of the API is also fundamentally different. For example, rather than calling the API to get the user's next key press, you register an event handler and the API calls you when the user presses a key. Of course (modern) Windows requires 32-bit or 64-bit code too (which also means very different calling conventions).

The result is that it's probably easier to design and write a new program for Windows (instead of converting an old program for DOS).

With this in mind; a better first step would be to convert the original program's source code into a document that describes its behavior (in plain English with no executable code).